# How to convert Wordpress website to HTML static website?

Tags: html, wordpress

at present I am using wordpress for my website https://propaura.com but I want to convert it to static HTML site ,how can I do?
and which is more better wordpress or HTML site.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest Httrack, but that would only copy the front end of the website. You still need to make it dynamic with PHP since it's built with WordPress.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use This Plugin "Export WP Page to Static HTML/CSS"
And Export the full site as HTML with related pages linking